# How do I translate SQL SERVER Query into Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-migration

I'm trying to translate the query below from SQL Server to Oracle SQL. I'm unsure
about the IFF condition for the oracle.

```
SELECT IIF(Grade<8, NULL,Name) As Name ,Grade,Marks 
FROM Grade,Students 
WHERE Marks>=Min_Mark and Marks<=Max_Mark 
ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name ASC;
```

Comment: You should stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause and switch to an explicit `JOIN` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below

```
SELECT case when Grade<8 then  NULL else Name end As Name ,Grade,Marks 
FROM Grade,Students 
WHERE Marks>=Min_Mark and Marks<=Max_Mark 
ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name ASC;
```

but i prefer explicit join like below

```
SELECT case when Grade<8 then  NULL else Name end As Name ,Grade,Marks 
    FROM Grade join Students 
    on  Grade.Marks>=Students.Min_Mark and
       Grade.Marks<=Students.Max_Mark 
    ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name ASC;
```

Comment: Almost everyone agrees on the second query being best practice

Comment: Thanks for answering. Very beneficial indeed.